# Displaying nested children's child components in Angular2 Dart

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to get the following working in Angular2 Dart:

```
    <div class='test'>
        <accordion2>
            <accordion-item-2 title="blah" active="true">
                <sample-form-1></sample-form-1>
            </accordion-item-2>
            <accordion-item-2>
                <sample-form-2></sample-form-2>
            </accordion-item-2>
            <accordion-item-2>
                <sample-form-3></sample-form-3>
            </accordion-item-2>
        </accordion2>
    </div>
```

I've previously used a directive to change `sample-form-x` into an `accordion-item`, I'm trying to get the following working without using directives.

My `accordion-item-2` is just a wrapper class to keep content in:

```
@Component(selector: 'accordion-item-2')
class AccordionItem2 {

    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) TemplateRef template;

    @ContentChildren(ContentChildren)
    QueryList<ContentChildren> children;

    @Input("active") bool active = true;
    @Input("title") String title = "No Title";

}
```

Upon displaying it, everything renders except for the sample forms:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'accordion2',
    // language=HTML
    template: """
        <ul class="accordion" 
            [attr.id]="id"
            [attr.data-accordion]="true" 
            [attr.slide-speed]="slideSpeed"
            [attr.multi-expand]="multiExpand"
            [attr.allow-all-closed]="allowAllClosed">
            <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items">
                <li class="accordion-item" [ngClass.is-active="item.active"] data-accordion-item>           
                    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">{{item.title}}</a>
                    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                        <template ngFor let-child [ngForOf]="item.children">
                            <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="child"></template>
                        </template>
                    </div>
                </li>   
            </template>
        </ul>
    """,
    directives: const [
        AccordionItem2, NgTemplateOutlet
    ]
)
class Accordion2 implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {

    @ContentChildren(AccordionItem2) QueryList<AccordionItem2> items;
    @Input() int slideSpeed = 100;
    @Input() bool multiExpand = true;
    @Input() bool allowAllClosed = true;

    String id = IdProvider.generateId(prefix: "accordion");

}
```

I've also tried :

```
<div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"></template>
    </template>
</div>
```

But no success.

Is it possible to do this without directives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

`child` in

```
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="child">
```

isn't a `TemplateRef`, therefore nothing to render for `ngTemplateOutlet`

You get templates explicitly by using `<template>` or implicitly by structural directives (with `*` prefix). 
Both doesn't seem to be the case in the code in your question.